# How to deal with questions whose answers are simply "Google"

Tags: discussion

For example,

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/which-skills-to-train

I can't really see that there is really any scope for proper answers for this question, since it seems to come down to common sense. "See what jobs are out there". Am I wrong? How are questions like this handled?

Even a list of what skills are in demand is not a great answer because it would be ever changing, opinion based and broad. My gut reaction is to close but I don't know if that's too harsh.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the way I just did... Closed as too broad. It is also way to opinion-based, and unlikely to get a specific answer, without duplicating a lot of information.